# react-table render component inside data

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I'm attempting to add a component inside the data using react-table package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-table#example)

Using the example from the package readme, I'm trying to use a fancy component to add an image to a cell:
using ** to jump out in the code...
I have also tried:

```
imageUrl:{<PlaceholderImage width={60} textColor="#fff" text="Image"/>}
```

example:

```
import ReactTable from 'react-table'
import 'react-table/react-table.css'
**import { PlaceholderImage } from 'react-placeholder-image'**

render() {
  const data = [{
    name: 'Tanner Linsley',
    age: 26,
**imageUrl:<PlaceholderImage width={60} textColor="#fff" text="Image"/>,**
    friend: {
      name: 'Jason Maurer',
      age: 23,
    }
  },{
    ...
  }]

  const columns = [{
    Header: 'Name',
    accessor: 'name' // String-based value accessors!
  }, {
    Header: 'Age',
    accessor: 'age',
    Cell: props => <span className='number'>{props.value}</span> // Custom cell components!
  }, {
    Header: ' ',
    accessor: 'imageUrl', // String-based value accessors!
    maxWidth: 70,
    minWidth:70,
  },{
    id: 'friendName', // Required because our accessor is not a string
    Header: 'Friend Name',
    accessor: d => d.friend.name // Custom value accessors!
  }, {
    Header: props => <span>Friend Age</span>, // Custom header components!
    accessor: 'friend.age'
  }]

  return <ReactTable
    data={data}
    columns={columns}
  />
}
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You're passing a react component to a data field that expects a string. Try customising your cell via `Cell` props:

```
const columns = [
  {
    Header: "Image",
    accessor: "imageUrl",
    maxWidth: 70,
    minWidth: 70,
    Cell: props => <PlaceholderImage width={60} textColor="#fff" text="Image" />
  }
];
```

Comment: Creator and maintainer of React-Table here... This is the correct answer.

Comment: What if we want to generate this on the backend? Anywhere we want to define columns we have to do it in JSX. If we can get access to properties `cell.column.attribute` we can render it our own way, but it seems that goes against the way this library is supposed to be used..

Answer (score 24):

In addition to @Clarity's answer, there's also a possibility to access the cell's value at the `Cell`'s property level:

```
const columns = [
  {
    Header: "Image",
    accessor: "imageUrl",
    maxWidth: 70,
    minWidth: 70,
    Cell: ({ cell: { value } }) => (
      <img
        src={value}
        width={60}
      />
    )
  }
];
```

Comment: I like this answer...just a slight edit, add a closing curly bracket in ({ cell: { value }) to become ({ cell: { value }})